# Get Results of Two Datasets Without UNION

Tags: sql-server, union, openquery

I am writing a stored procedure to retrieve purchases out of Microsoft Great Plains so they can be processed.

Great Plains has two invoice table sets of note.  SOP10100/SOP10200 contain the invoice header and details of an invoice that has not yet been posted.  SOP30200/SOP30300 contain the invoice header and details of invoices that have been posted.  When a product is purchased, it immediately goes into SOP10100/SOP10200, and once it is posted, it is moved from SOP10100/SOP10200  to SOP30200/SOP30300.  There is a common table SOP10106 that contains user-defined fields and can be joined to either table set.

When pulling purchases, we need to check both tables in case an invoice gets posted before it can be processed.  Up until now, the only way we've been able to achieve this is through a UNION, which is basically two identical queries with the difference being that one joins to SOP10100/SOP10200 and the other joins to SOP30200/SOP30300.

I'm hoping to find a way that we can pare this down into a single query (utilizing the shared SOP10106 table) to hopefully get one result set that only contains the records that have either a SOP10100/SOP10200 or SOP30200/SOP30300 record.  The join to the GP tables is within the OPENQUERY function.

The SPROC is below:

```
SELECT [Account1].AccountID, [Account1].AccountNumber AS 'Order_OrgID', [Account2].AccountNumber AS 'CI_OrgID', [Contact].cncy_CustomerNumber AS 'CustomerID', [Contact].EMailAddress1 AS 'Email', [Contact].FirstName, [Contact].LastName, [StringMapMarket].Value AS 'Market', 
GP.Invoice, GP.SKU, MAP.Name, GP.OrderDate, GP.Quantity, GP.SLPRSNID, RTRIM(GP.SKU) + '-' + [StringMapMarket].Value COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT as AdjSku, MAP.CourseID, MAP.SubscriptionID
FROM OPENQUERY(GPSERVER, 'SELECT [SOP10100].SOPNUMBE AS Invoice, [SOP10200].ITEMNMBR AS SKU, [SOP10200].ITEMDESC AS Product, [SOP10100].CREATDDT AS OrderDate, [SOP10200].QTYORDER AS Quantity,
               [SOP10100].SLPRSNID, [SOP10100].CUSTNMBR, [SOP10106].USERDEF1, [SOP10100].SOPTYPE, [SOP10100].VOIDSTTS
               FROM CPI.dbo.SOP10100 WITH (NOLOCK)
               INNER JOIN CPI.dbo.SOP10200 WITH (NOLOCK)  ON [SOP10100].SOPNUMBE = [SOP10200].SOPNUMBE AND [SOP10100].CREATDDT > DATEADD(ww,-4,GETDATE())
               INNER JOIN CPI.dbo.SOP10106 WITH (NOLOCK)  ON [SOP10100].SOPNUMBE = [SOP10106].SOPNUMBE WHERE [SOP10200].SOPTYPE = 3
               AND [SOP10100].VOIDSTTS <> 1
               AND NOT [SOP10106].USERDEF1 = ''INTERNAL LMS''') as GP
INNER JOIN [CRMSERVER].CPI_MSCRM.dbo.Account AS [Account1] WITH(NOLOCK) ON GP.CUSTNMBR = [Account1].AccountNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
INNER JOIN [CRMSERVER].CPI_MSCRM.dbo.Contact WITH(NOLOCK) ON GP.USERDEF1 = [Contact].cncy_customernumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
INNER JOIN [CRMSERVER].CPI_MSCRM.dbo.Account AS [Account2] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [Contact].ParentCustomerId = [Account2].Id
INNER JOIN CPIProcessData.dbo.StringMap AS [StringMapMarket] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [Account1].cncy_MarketType = [StringMapMarket].AttributeValue AND [StringMapMarket].AttributeName = 'cncy_MarketType' AND [StringMapMarket].ObjectTypeCode = 2
INNER JOIN CPIProcessData.dbo.StringMap AS [StringMapCountry] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [Contact].cncy_address1country = [StringMapCountry].AttributeValue AND [StringMapCountry].AttributeName = 'cncy_address1country' AND [StringMapMarket].ObjectTypeCode = 2
INNER JOIN CPIProcessData.dbo.vwLmsMapping AS MAP WITH(NOLOCK) ON MAP.Subscription = 'true' AND 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN [StringMapCountry].Value IN ('US','Canada') THEN RTRIM(GP.SKU) + '-' + 
                            CASE
                               WHEN [StringMapMarket].Value IN ('HE','MH') THEN 'HE'
                               WHEN [StringMapMarket].Value IN ('ED') THEN 'ED'
                               ELSE 'HS'
                            END
                        ELSE RTRIM(GP.SKU) 
                    END = map.SKU
LEFT OUTER JOIN SeatLog WITH(NOLOCK) ON GP.Invoice = [SeatLog].Invoice AND RTRIM(GP.SKU) = [SeatLog].SKU
WHERE GP.SOPTYPE = 3
AND GP.VOIDSTTS <> 1
AND NOT GP.USERDEF1 = 'INTERNAL LMS'
AND [SubscriptionLog].ID IS NULL

UNION

SELECT [Account1].AccountID, [Account1].AccountNumber AS 'Order_OrgID', [Account2].AccountNumber AS 'CI_OrgID', [Contact].cncy_CustomerNumber AS 'CustomerID', [Contact].EMailAddress1 AS 'Email', [Contact].FirstName, [Contact].LastName, [StringMapMarket].Value AS 'Market', 
GP.Invoice, GP.SKU, MAP.Name, GP.OrderDate, GP.Quantity, GP.SLPRSNID, RTRIM(GP.SKU) + '-' + [StringMapMarket].Value COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT as AdjSku, MAP.CourseID, MAP.SubscriptionID
FROM OPENQUERY(GPSERVER, 'SELECT [SOP30200].SOPNUMBE AS Invoice, [SOP30300].ITEMNMBR AS SKU, [SOP30300].ITEMDESC AS Product, [SOP30200].CREATDDT AS OrderDate, [SOP30300].QTYORDER AS Quantity,
               [SOP30200].SLPRSNID, [SOP30200].CUSTNMBR, [SOP10106].USERDEF1, [SOP30200].SOPTYPE, [SOP30200].VOIDSTTS
               FROM CPI.dbo.SOP30200 WITH (NOLOCK)
               INNER JOIN CPI.dbo.SOP30300 WITH (NOLOCK)  ON [SOP30200].SOPNUMBE = [SOP30300].SOPNUMBE AND [SOP30200].CREATDDT > DATEADD(ww,-4,GETDATE())
               INNER JOIN CPI.dbo.SOP10106 WITH (NOLOCK)  ON [SOP30200].SOPNUMBE = [SOP10106].SOPNUMBE WHERE [SOP30300].SOPTYPE = 3
               AND [SOP30200].VOIDSTTS <> 1
               AND NOT [SOP10106].USERDEF1 = ''INTERNAL LMS''') as GP
INNER JOIN [CRMSERVER].CPI_MSCRM.dbo.Account AS [Account1] WITH(NOLOCK) ON GP.CUSTNMBR = [Account1].AccountNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
INNER JOIN [CRMSERVER].CPI_MSCRM.dbo.Contact WITH(NOLOCK) ON GP.USERDEF1 = [Contact].cncy_customernumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
INNER JOIN [CRMSERVER].CPI_MSCRM.dbo.Account AS [Account2] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [Contact].ParentCustomerId = [Account2].Id
INNER JOIN CPIProcessData.dbo.StringMap AS [StringMapMarket] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [Account1].cncy_MarketType = [StringMapMarket].AttributeValue AND [StringMapMarket].AttributeName = 'cncy_MarketType' AND [StringMapMarket].ObjectTypeCode = 2
INNER JOIN CPIProcessData.dbo.StringMap AS [StringMapCountry] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [Contact].cncy_address1country = [StringMapCountry].AttributeValue AND [StringMapCountry].AttributeName = 'cncy_address1country' AND [StringMapMarket].ObjectTypeCode = 2
INNER JOIN CPIProcessData.dbo.vwLmsMapping AS MAP WITH(NOLOCK) ON MAP.Subscription = 'true' AND 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN [StringMapCountry].Value IN ('US','Canada') THEN RTRIM(GP.SKU) + '-' + 
                            CASE
                               WHEN [StringMapMarket].Value IN ('HE','MH') THEN 'HE'
                               WHEN [StringMapMarket].Value IN ('ED') THEN 'ED'
                               ELSE 'HS'
                            END
                        ELSE RTRIM(GP.SKU) 
                    END = map.SKU
LEFT OUTER JOIN SeatLog WITH(NOLOCK) ON GP.Invoice = [SeatLog].Invoice AND RTRIM(GP.SKU) = [SeatLog].SKU
WHERE GP.SOPTYPE = 3
AND GP.VOIDSTTS <> 1
AND NOT GP.USERDEF1 = 'INTERNAL LMS'
AND [SubscriptionLog].ID IS NULL
```

Does anyone know of any ideas to simplify this without having to use a UNION?  I'm hoping to improve the performance.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a linked server? I assume you are across two machines here, right? In any case, why not push the union off to your inner query so that the remote part on executes once (though still using a union)? You also definitely want to include the where clauses in your embedded query to reduce the data returned.

Comment: `UNION ALL` generally performs better than `UNION` because its not de-duping the results.

Comment: @Dale Burrell - I tried the UNION ALL and it only saved about 4 seconds.

Comment: @TomC - I attempted to put the entire UNION into the OPENQUERY and added the WHERE clauses to it and it's not really improving performance.

Comment: I'm trying to do some manipulation with FULL JOIN and COALESCE, but that ran even longer.

Comment: @Ryan if you run the whole Union on the remote server, what is the performance? What is the size of the result ? What if you run two separate queries. Is the sun of the runtime better or worse? BTW, these filters seem redundant as they are already applied on the remote query

Comment: And just to confirm - the CPI database is on a different server, hence the OPENQUERY, is  that correct? And you are not able to create a linked server to it?

Comment: @TomC - there is a Linked server, that's what the 'GPSERVER' parameter on the OPENQUERY is.  But yes, the CPI database is on the server that the linked server GPSERVER is pointing to.

Comment: I would suggest looking at where the performance issue really is. Try the remote parts by themselves, as you may find that is slow in which case you cant do much in the rest of the query until you fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it a different way by using FULL JOIN and COALESCE as follows:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Table1.SOPNUMBE, Table2.SOPNUMBE) AS 'SOPNUMBE', COALESCE(Table1.ITEMNMBR, Table2.ITEMNMBR) AS 'SKU', COALESCE(Table1.CUSTNMBR, Table2.CUSTNMBR) AS 'Account_Number', [SubscriptionLog].ID
FROM (SELECT SOP10100.SOPNUMBE,SOP10200.ITEMNMBR,SOP10100.CUSTNMBR FROM [GPSERVER].CPI.dbo.SOP10100 INNER JOIN [GPSERVER].CPI.dbo.SOP10200 ON SOP10100.SOPNUMBE = SOP10200.SOPNUMBE) AS Table1
FULL JOIN (SELECT SOP30200.SOPNUMBE,SOP30300.ITEMNMBR,SOP30200.CUSTNMBR FROM [GPSERVER].CPI.dbo.SOP30200 INNER JOIN [GPSERVER].CPI.dbo.SOP30300 ON SOP30200.SOPNUMBE = SOP30300.SOPNUMBE) AS Table2 ON Table1.SOPNUMBE = Table2.SOPNUMBE AND Table1.ITEMNMBR = Table2.ITEMNMBR AND Table1.CUSTNMBR = Table2.CUSTNMBR
INNER JOIN [GPSERVER].CPI.dbo.SOP10106 WITH(NOLOCK) ON COALESCE(Table1.SOPNUMBE, Table2.SOPNUMBE) = SOP10106.SOPNUMBE
INNER JOIN [CRMSERVER].CPI_MSCRM.dbo.Account AS [Account1] WITH(NOLOCK) ON COALESCE(Table1.CUSTNMBR, Table2.CUSTNMBR) = [Account1].AccountNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
INNER JOIN [CRMSERVER].CPI_MSCRM.dbo.Contact WITH(NOLOCK) ON SOP10106.USERDEF1 = [Contact].cncy_customernumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
--INNER JOIN [CRMSERVER].CPI_MSCRM.dbo.Account AS [Account2] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [Contact].ParentCustomerId = [Account2].Id
INNER JOIN CPIProcessData.dbo.StringMap AS [StringMapMarket] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [Account1].cncy_MarketType = [StringMapMarket].AttributeValue AND [StringMapMarket].AttributeName = 'cncy_MarketType' AND [StringMapMarket].ObjectTypeCode = 2
INNER JOIN CPIProcessData.dbo.StringMap AS [StringMapCountry] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [Contact].cncy_address1country = [StringMapCountry].AttributeValue AND [StringMapCountry].AttributeName = 'cncy_address1country' AND [StringMapMarket].ObjectTypeCode = 2
INNER JOIN CPIProcessData.dbo.vwLmsMapping AS MAP WITH(NOLOCK) ON MAP.Subscription = 'true' AND 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN [StringMapCountry].Value IN ('US','Canada') THEN RTRIM(COALESCE(Table1.ITEMNMBR, Table2.ITEMNMBR)) + '-' + 
                                CASE
                                   WHEN [StringMapMarket].Value IN ('HE','MH') THEN 'HE'
                                   WHEN [StringMapMarket].Value IN ('ED') THEN 'ED'
                                   ELSE 'HS'
                                END
                            ELSE RTRIM(COALESCE(Table1.ITEMNMBR, Table2.ITEMNMBR)) 
                        END = map.SKU
LEFT OUTER JOIN [SubscriptionLog] WITH(NOLOCK) ON SOP10106.SOPNUMBE = [SubscriptionLog].Invoice AND RTRIM(COALESCE(Table1.ITEMNMBR, Table2.ITEMNMBR)) = [SubscriptionLog].SKU
WHERE [SubscriptionLog].ID IS NULL
```

It seems to run a little better, but it returns duplicates and not the results I expect.